# What are JKZD and JKNZD?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, disassembly, xeon-phi

Looking through Zydis ( https://github.com/zyantific/zydis/blob/57be5b1d1b9dd99830b89caac928add64ad5d072/include/Zydis/Generated/EnumMnemonic.h ) mnemonics I found these:

```
ZYDIS_MNEMONIC_JKNZD,
ZYDIS_MNEMONIC_JKZD,
```

I couldn't find these mnemonics anywhere else; what instructions do they represent?

What operations do these instructions perform?

`Z` and `NZ` would likely indicate zero and not zero respectively, and `J` likely stands for jump, but `K` and `D`?

Edit: I found this old intel document, but it makes no sense:

http://www.cism.ucl.ac.be/Services/Formations/ICS/ics_2013.0.028/vtune_amplifier_xe/documentation/en/instructions/327364001EN.pdf

It states (page 75) that JKZD is encoded as VEX.NDS.128.0F.W0 84 id.

Comment: What's Zydis?  Those aren't x86 instructions, and you don't have any other tags that would shed any light on where they come from.

Comment: Zydis is an x86 disassembler. Added a link.

Comment: Given that it's not referenced anywhere else in the source tree (just the auto-generated and the `ZYDIS_MAKE_SHORTSTRING("jkzd")` https://github.com/zyantific/zydis/search?q=JKZD&unscoped_q=JKZD), there's no way to know why it's there.  Except maybe if there's a mention in a git commit message.  Unless something indexes that array element with a numeric constant or reaches it in a loop?  Anyway, it's not an x86 instruction.  You might want to open an issue on their github to point out that these aren't instructions.  Either it was a bug or they'll explain why it's there.

Comment: @PeterCordes Edited with another source.

Comment: Ah, interesting, yeah Knight's Corner has its own version of what later became AVX-512.  So there you go,  KNC had instructions like `jrcxz` but for mask registers (which KNC and AVX-512 call `k0..k7`) to let you compare-and-branch in one instruction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You already answered your own question with that Intel Knight's Corner link.  KNC had its own version of what later became AVX-512, with incompatible machine-code encodings.

As documented in that Intel manual, KNC had instructions like `jrcxz` but for mask registers (which KNC and AVX-512 call `k0..k7`) to let you compare-and-branch in one instruction on a vector compare-into-mask result.  JKZD - Jump near if mask is zero.  It has 2 forms, `jkzd k1, rel32` and `jkzd k1, rel8`

These are not standard instructions and don't appear in Intel's mainstream manuals (which include AVX-512).  In AVX-512, you branch on a mask register value with `ktest k1,k1` or `kortest k1,k1` to set regular FLAGS, then use a regular branch condition.  (With unrolling to get 2 vector compare results, you can branch on *either* of them being non-zero with `kortest k1,k2` with 2 separate registers.)